# Ubuntu md5 verify from windows

Tags: windows-8

i need the windows 8 equivalent command of Linux `md5sum`  in order to check the Ubuntu .ISO from a windows 8 machine .

thanks

Comment: This question isn't about Ubuntu http://superuser.com/q/89191/252532

Comment: so if i need to install ubuntu checking the integrity for my safety, because the laptop i bout came with windows 8 you would´t  help me ??

Comment: @LiveWireBT Checking the hash of a downloaded Ubuntu ISO is part of the process of installing Ubuntu. When someone has trouble finding the correct download, we help them find it, even if they are using Windows. We tell people how to create bootable USB drives to install Ubuntu, and how to burn a DVD to install Ubuntu, even when this involves telling them how to do something in Windows. We tell them where to go to verify and disable Windows dynamic disks, if they need to do that in order to enable Ubuntu to install. There's no reason to consider md5summing the Ubuntu ISO in Windows off-topic.

Comment: @EliahKagan To me this is a software recommendation for Windows. The answers to the question on SU even go beyond simply suggesting the md5sum equivalent for Windows (which would be cygwin). Also if some one asks a similar question on U&L, they would find the same recommendations in the same place and wouldn't have to search AU too. Despite being not very elaborate in my first comment, I was more considerate than what you think of me. You can stop framing me as a Windows-hater, because I'm not.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I have no idea why you think I am framing you as a "Windows-hater," nor do I see the relevance of one's views on Windows to this question or my comment.  I don't think you're inconsiderate; I think you are mistaken in your belief that this question isn't about Ubuntu. We support users through the whole process of installing Ubuntu, and it seems to me that must include, at minimum, all the common or recommended steps in doing so. Regarding overlapping site scopes, see "Respecting your own community" in: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [MD5SUM on Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows) section of the [HowToMD5SUM help wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) says, it used to be that no md5sum-checking utility was included in Windows. If you're using a very old version of Windows, or just prefer to use a GUI tool, then you can download a utility online to verify the md5 hash of your downloaded Ubuntu ISO image. WinMD5Sum (by [Nullriver Software](http://www.nullriver.com/)) is one such utility.

> 1. Download and install [winMD5Sum](http://www.nullriver.com/downloads/Install-winMd5Sum.exe), a free and open source hash verification program.
> 2. Right-click the ISO file.
> 3. Click Send To, then winMD5Sum.
> 4. Wait for winMD5Sum to load and finish the checksum (this may take a significant amount of time depending on your computer's performance).
> 5. Copy the corresponding hash from [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) into the bottom text box.
> 6. Click "Compare"   [image: screenshot of WinMD5Sum checking the MD5 hash of a downloaded Ubuntu ISO image]
> 7. A message box will say "MD5 Check Sums are the same" if the hashes are equal.

<sup>Excerpted from [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) by "Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki," reproduced here [in compliance with the license](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License).</sup>

The screenshot looks like Windows XP but the  WinMD5Sum utility works on current versions of Windows as well. I have used it successfully on Windows 7, 8, and 8.1.

Note that all recent versions of Windows do include a utility, `certutil`, that can be used for this purpose. See [sBeDs's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245195/22949) for details.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the `certutil` command in Windows, which does not require installing any additional software.

Open a command prompt, `cd` to wherever your iso is, then type in:

```
certutil -hashfile filename.iso MD5
```

Then you just have to compare the output with the md5 on the download page! :p

Comment: I agree more with this method as it requires no download at all. It also supports sha methods, just need to replace "md5" to your sha version.

Comment: This works, I had to use `-hashfile` and `SHA256` to get the correct hash. Like this `certutil -hashfile ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso sha256`. Also, Ubuntu list their hashes at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ rather than the download page, which wasn't obvious.