# Can't boot on Lenovo Ideapad 110 14ast

Tags: dual-boot, usb, lenovo

I tried to install Ubuntu 19.10 alongside dualboot with my Windows 10, I succeded created a bootable usb with Rufus in Windows 10. I did reboot my pc and started boot menu I choosed My USB Flashdisk as primary boot option, after a while the screen show the grub of ubuntu there are some options and I entered Install Ubuntu.
The screen goes black a while and the error messages appeared with "**Initramfs unpacking failed: broken padding**" in the top of the message.
What is This messages? 
How to resolve This? 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, but my guess (or where I'd start) is the ISO download was imperfect (did you check it? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) OR write to install media failed? (did you verify that? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any install media, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/etc)

Comment: Better practice is to always verify your image using SHA256 or MD5 checksum after download. Here is head-start [Ubuntu md5 verify from windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607813/ubuntu-md5-verify-from-windows). Mentioned utility could be helpful or [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) similar one for your platform. For  Linux platform it is quite easy, visit [VerifyIsoHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto), [HowToSHA256SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM), [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)