# Verify ubuntu iso on Win7

Tags: windows-7

I run the powrershel as administrator with
CertUtil -hashfile .\ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso  and I get SHA1 checksum
but if I put (sha256 at the end)
CertUtil -hashfile .\ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso **sha256** the command fails??????

Not sure how to verify sha256.

Comment: Try SHA256 (uppercase letter).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu md5 verify from windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607813/ubuntu-md5-verify-from-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help from the command line :

```
C:\Users\em444>certutil -hashfile -?
Usage:
  CertUtil [Options] -hashfile InFile [HashAlgorithm]
  Generate and display cryptographic hash over a file
Options:
  ../..
Hash algorithms: MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512
```

So right syntax is :

```
CertUtil -hashfile .\ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso SHA256
```